# Python - pandas explode rows by turns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below.

```
df = DataFrame([{'B1': '1C', 'B2': '', 'B3': '', },
                {'B1': '3A', 'B2': '1A', 'B3': ''},
                {'B1': '41A', 'B2': '28A', 'B3': '3A'}])

    B1   B2  B3    
0   1C             
1   3A   1A      
2  41A  28A  3A
```

Now I extracted letters from **B1-B3** and add to new columns **U1-U3** get:

```
    B1   B2  B3  U1 U2 U3 
0   1C            C         
1   3A   1A       A  A      
2  41A  28A  3A   A  A  A
```

and I want to let the row to explode like this:

```
    B1   B2  B3   U1  U2  U3 
0   1C            C         
1   3A   1A       A         
2   3A   1A            A      
3  41A  28A  3A   A         
4  41A  28A  3A        A      
5  41A  28A  3A            A
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your original df will only have columns B1 B2 & B3, I suppose?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it needs 3 step solution of

1) extracting the Alphabates from data and creating new columns,

2) duplicating the rows w.r.t values and

3) masking with identity matrix.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'B1': '1C', 'B2': '', 'B3': '', },
            {'B1': '3A', 'B2': '1A', 'B3': ''},
            {'B1': '41A', 'B2': '28A', 'B3': '3A'}])

    B1  B2  B3
0   1C      
1   3A  1A  
2   41A 28A 3A
```

1) Extracting the Alphabates from the rows and assigning as columns

```
df = df.merge(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('([A-Za-z])')).add_prefix('U_'), left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer')
```

Out:

```
  B1    B2  B3  U_B1    U_B2    U_B3
0   1C          C   NaN NaN
1   3A  1A      A   A   NaN
2   41A 28A 3A  A   A   A
```

2) You can try of `duplicating the rows` of dataframe wherever it has more than 1 value

```
# Duplicating the rows of dataframe
val = df[['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3']].notnull().sum(axis=1)
df1 = df.loc[np.repeat(val.index,val)]
```

-> 3) then by grouping with index, pick only `masked values of identity matrix`(**np.identity**) w.r.t length of each group.

```
df1[['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3']] = df1.groupby(df1.index)['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3'].apply(lambda x: x.dropna(axis=1).mask(np.identity(len(x))==0))
```

Out:

```
   B1   B2  B3  U_B1 U_B2 U_B3
0   1C          C       
1   3A  1A      A       
1   3A  1A          A   
2   41A 28A 3A  A       
2   41A 28A 3A      A   
2   41A 28A 3A          A
```

Comment: In the original df, columns U1 ec. doesn't exist

Comment: @RahulAgarwal i just edited my response to incorporate the change :-)

Comment: at the line `df = df.merge` it shows `If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: I checked it again, can you pass the json form of your dataframe ?

Comment: And I found that other line of code is ok to run, using the second block as df in my question which has extracted alphabates

Comment: @xiumpt Can you check it now, i just changed column names , it is working fine for me :-|